# OpenApi's typeMapping Date=Date is not working

Tags: java, typescript, maven, openapi, type-mapping

I am having trouble generating the client code with the right type mapping. My client is broken because fields of type `date` are generated as `string` :

```
//Server code (Java)
@ApiModel(description = "ContractExtensionDto")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContractExtensionDto {
    @NotNull
    protected Integer id;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = PatternConfig.DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
    protected Date dateStart;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = PatternConfig.DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
    protected Date dateEnd;
    //omitted code
}

//Generated client code (Typescript)
export interface ContractExtensionDto { 
    id: number;
    dateStart?: string;
    dateEnd?: string;
    //omitted code
}
```

In my pom.xml I have added both `typeMappings` and `importMappings` :

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>${project.build.directory}/classes/swagger/swagger.json</inputSpec>
                    <generatorName>typescript-angular</generatorName>
                    <output>frontend/src/app/services/rest-api</output>
                    <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                    <configOptions>
                        <ngVersion>10.2.5</ngVersion>
                        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    </configOptions>
                    <typeMappings>Date=Date</typeMappings>
                    <importMappings>Date=Date</importMappings>
                    <!-- I have tried this as well but in vain -->
                    <!-- 
                      <typeMappings>DateTime=Date</typeMappings>
                      <importMappings>DateTime=Date</importMappings>
                    -->
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

but still the client `date` fields are generated as `string` typed.

Comment: By the way, both `Date` classes bundled with Java are terribly flawed by poor design. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

Define `typeMappings` as below, instead:

```
<typeMappings>
    <mapping>DateTime=Date</mapping>
    <mapping>Date=Date</mapping>
</typeMappings>
```

This worked with `typescript-angular` generator, at least.